# Android Application Closes Without Opening

Tags: java, android

I'm watching the Logcat, but I can't find out where the problem is. I'm trying to design a user login page, but the application closes before it even opens. I can't figure out what the problem is. There are no error warnings.

```
2019-12-29 19:14:31.981 2076-2165/ceyizci.com.android E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@f64d785
2019-12-29 19:14:31.982 2076-2165/ceyizci.com.android E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@d7879da
2019-12-29 19:14:32.089 2076-2115/ceyizci.com.android E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2019-12-29 19:14:32.530 2076-2076/ceyizci.com.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ceyizci.com.android, PID: 2076
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ceyizci.com.android/ceyizci.com.android.LoginActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:421)
        at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:4490)
        at ceyizci.com.android.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: You have to use `Theme.AppCompat` in your application. Add `style/theme.xml` and `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I did that, but nothing changed. Logcat updated. Will you look again?

Comment: upload the code of activity which is crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"requestFeature() must be called before adding content"

You can't call requestFeature after calling setContentView.  You have to do it before.